# SQL Server External table

Tags: external

0

I have SQL Server 2016. I want to create external table to reference another database schema. I have database name clients and want to query database name Courier.client table. getting error creating external table

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'.

querying data from clients database from CC database client table

Comment: From your question, how do you think people can help you???  Please follow this guide on how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you post the actual query string that's giving you the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.